# Can I safely use <span> instead of <div> for Bootstrap 2 scaffolding?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I just noticed that replacing `<div>` with `<span>` in Bootstrap scaffolding seems to work just fine:

```
<label>
    <span class="row-fluid">
        <span class="span6">
            // First column
        </span>

        <span class="span6">
            // Second column
        </span>
    </span>
<label>
```

But is that a supported and documented use case?

As illustrated above, I'd like to use a `.row-fluid` inside a `<label>`, but a `<div>` inside a `<label>` would not validate.

Answer (score 0):

Both span and div seems to work fine in Bootstrap 2.3.2

Try pasting the code below in http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/starter-template.html

```
<label>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">
            // First column
        </div>

        <div class="span6">
            // Second column
        </div>
    </div>
</label>
```

Comment: As mentioned above, this code [does not validate](http://validator.w3.org/). Also, I've tested it with `<span>` and I know it works, I'm just concerned about whether it is *supported*, and will work cross-browser without unexpected side effects!